# Run the count down or up function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdown

i wrote a function which do count down or up the numbers to another by pressing a button.
look at this :

```
var timer;
function counterFn(element,oldCount,newCount,speed) {
    if(isNaN(speed)) speed=100;
    clearInterval(timer);
    if(oldCount===newCount) {
        element.text(newCount);
        return;
    }
    var counter=oldCount;
    timer=setInterval(function() {
        if(oldCount<newCount) {
            if(counter>newCount)
                clearInterval(timer);
            counter++;
        } else {
            if(counter<newCount)
                clearInterval(timer);
            counter--;
        }
        if(counter===newCount) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.text(counter);
    },speed);
}
$('.button').on("click",function() {
  counterFn('.endelement',10,100,1);
});
```

description of the function attributes:

```
element : the element which will show the result
oldCount : is the start number
newCount : is the end number
speed : is the repeat time of setInterval
```

now, according to above code, if you press the element with `.button` class, `counterFn` function will run. now if you press the button again (before clearing the `setinterval` by the function), every thing is OK.

this is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hgh2hgh/gpvn9hcq/4/
as you can see, clicking on the button, clear the previous interval and run the new one.

now if the second element call that function like this :

```
$('.button2').on("click",function() {
  counterFn('.endelement2',50,70,2);
});
```

naturally the second request will stop the timer and run new timer with the new attributes. cause a global variable is defined for just one `setInterval`.

look at the comments for demolink of this part : [1] in comments

if definition of the variable be inside the function, pressing the button twice, mean running the function for two separate time.

look at the comments for demolink of this part : [2] in comments

OK, now how to run this function correct?

thanks.

Comment: a way is passing the variable to function, mean define a global variable and then pass it into function. But how?

Comment: Use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) around each one to create a locally scoped `timer` variable for each, or, y'know, use two variables. Best not to use global variables either. It would also help to create a working demo http://jsfiddle.net of your code.

Comment: each timer is global, so definition of the timers locally, is not good. is it? Maybe the function called by thousand time. should i define thousand variable then name all of them inside the function? OK i will create demo.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/pczweoxs/ (and a variation: http://jsfiddle.net/pczweoxs/1/) Note, a working demonstration would help understand better.

Comment: [1] jsfiddle.net/hgh2hgh/e2pdhv6z , [2] jsfiddle.net/hgh2hgh/o6n67dnu

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hgh2hgh/pczweoxs/2/ it is the final code which i wanted. really thanks to  @Jared Farrish. i learned something new. :)